# Why is the root node not centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I'm trying to code a star graph, using the tikz `graphs` library. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \graph [clockwise=10, radius=1cm] {
        hidden -> \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {p\i/$P_{\i}$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image]

Why is the root node not centered? Shouldn't everything be nicely disposed around (0, 0)?

Comment: @Zarko, I am not a native speaker, but I am not sure your edit is correct. Apologies if you *are* a native speaker and I'm talking nonsense :)

Comment: Actually, your first title was syntaxically correct ;)

Comment: @SebGlav: ‘syntactically’.

Comment: Aha, of course ^^ Those mismatches between French and English. That was exactly the place to make this mistake. Thanks, Bernard.

Comment: You still can revert my correction of title.

Comment: I didn't want to be rude, and I'm also always second guessing my English :) I will now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plan is just to draw this particular circular graph, I would not use the `graphs` library but do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (h) {hidden};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
            \draw [->] (h) -- (126-36*\i:2) node[shift=(123-36*\i:8pt)] (p\i){$P_{\i}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circular graphs without graphs library]

Note that I used a radius of 2cm, because with only 1 cm, all nodes were too close from the centre, for my taste.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I do want to use graphs, as I plan to complicate the graph a bit from this MWE.

Comment: So the way you're doing it is wrong. [See this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563121/drawing-a-wheel-graph-with-tikz), for example.